# Marking unused parameters in functions passed as arguments

Tags: python, pylint, optional-parameters, unused-variables

I have a higher order function:

```
def mymap(f,...):
    ...
    x = f(a, logger)
    ...
```

and I need to pass to it `f` that *needs* only one argument:

```
def bigfun(...):
    ...
    def f(a, logger):
        return a
    mymap(f, ...)
    ...
```

the code above works fine, but `pylint` complains about

```
Unused argument 'logger' (unused-argument)
```

If I define `f` using `_`:

```
def bigfun(...):
    ...
    def f(a, _logger):
        return a
    mymap(f, ...)
    ...
```

the code breaks with

```
TypeError: bigfun.<locals>.f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logger'
```

I can, of course, add `# pylint: disable=unused-argument` to `f`, but is this TRT?

Comment: Why not use `**kwargs`?

Comment: @RandomDavis: because the code should be self-documenting if possible, and _in this case_, `kwargs` obfuscates the code.

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what comments were for.

Comment: I don't understand why you need `logger` if it's not even used in `f`?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco because other users of `mymap` will use it.

Comment: I don't see much value in self-documenting the arg that it doesn't need anyway. One option would be to have `mymap` call `f` by positional args (to avoid the "got an unexpected keyword argument" error when you use an underscore name). But the lint ignore rule seems fine here.

Comment: `def mymap(f,...):` isn't a thing. For this question I think a working example, including a real call signature, is important. things like inner function `f` that may or may not bind with local variables in `bigfun` and questions about `*args` and `**kwargs` could be clarified.

Comment: There are no keyword arguments in your code so you can't be getting that error. If you gave us the failing line, there would at least be something to guess at. But as stands, there isn't enough code to sort this out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: but just taking a step back, why not just ignore pylint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not shown in the code you gave but in order to raise "TypeError: bigfun..f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logger'", `mymap(f, ...)` must have been `mymap(f, logger=my_logger)` instead. If you change your function signature from `logger` to `_logger`, then the calling code with keyword args needs to use the new name (`mymap(f, _logger = my_logger)`) or become positional (`mymap(f, my_logger)`).